# How do I boot a Windows installation USB? I am not able to boot a Window installation USB but I can boot any Linux distro with USB

Tags: boot, uefi, windows, 22.04, live-usb

I installed Ubuntu to replace Windows 11 on a new laptop, deleting all of the partitions on my hard drive.

I tried to play GTA but was unhappy with the performace so I decided to reinstall Windows. I made a bootable USB of Windows and booted it.

When I was in the boot menu, I selected my USB but it won't boot Windows and only boots Ubuntu. I tried it several times with the same result. I believe the problem is Ubuntu and I tried to format my hard drive again. I used a bootable USB of Ubuntu and that one booted. Then I formatted my hard drive using the Ubuntu USB. Then I rebooted my laptop and my PC doesn't have any OS. I tried to boot the Windows USB again but it still won't boot. I select my USB drive, and I hit enter. But I'm still stuck in the boot menu.

Whenever I try to boot any Linux distro such as Ubuntu, Mint, Arch, PrimeOS, etc, it boots. When I try to boot Window it won't boot.

How can I boot a Windows installation USB?

Answer (score 0):

use gnome-disks to make a windows boot usb.
put the usb drive/stick into the usb port then go to where the windows ISO is.
right click the ISO and choose open with 'disk image writer'

follow the instructions and burn your boot usb.

restart and from the boot menu choose your usb stick to boot from ...